# formal Concept Analysis Tool

Tags: c#

I need an open source FCA (Formal Concept Analysis) tool build by .net (will be great if C# with any version)

I'm currently using ConExp 1.3 (java one) but I'm not perfect in Java.

so any body knows?

Comment: I finsihed my master and passed :) but I found many for them and I want to sahre with others https://github.com/fcatools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be late but here's a list of FCA tools:
http://www.fcahome.org.uk/fcasoftware.html

Answer (score 0):

There exists a very capable set of tools and libraries for python called py-galactic, but unfortunately the documentation is quite terse and technical.

Also, installing a 0.5.0 was not successful under a Conda environment. 0.4.0 seems to work perfectly. There are some rough edges in accessibility and a high learning curve but the libraries are very capable:

https://galactic.univ-lr.fr/

If there are other people using these libraries, I'd love to hear from you.